# How prove this integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^m\ln{x}}{x-1}dx=\sum_{r=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^2}$

Tags: integration

prove that
$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^m\ln{x}}{x-1}dx=\sum_{r=m+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{r^2}$$

This true?

my idea

let
$$I(m)=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^m}{x-1}dx\Longrightarrow I'(m)=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^m\ln{x}}{x-1}dx$$

and we must find
$$I(m)=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^m}{x-1}dx=-\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(1-t)^m}{t}dt$$
then we can't prove it.
Thank you everyone can help, and This problem is from:[How prove $\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^k}\sum_{t=k+1}^{n}\frac{1}{t^2}<e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435755/how-prove-frack1k1kk-sum-t-k1n-frac1t2e?lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Here is how,

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^m\ln{x}}{x-1}dx=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^{m+k}\ln(x)dx$$

$$= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ (k+m)^2+2(k+m)+1 }$$

$$ = \sum_{k=m}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ k^2+2k+1 }$$

$$ = \sum_{k=m}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ (k+1)^2 }= \sum_{r=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ r^2 }=\psi'(m+1),$$

where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

**Note:**

$$ \sum_{m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^2}=\psi'(m+1). $$

Comment: oh,Thank you, it's nice+1

Comment: @math110: You are welcome.

Comment: IMHO, it will be useful to include some justification why one is legal to exchange the order of integration and summation in the  first equality.

Comment: You can exchange the order of integration if you consider the series expansion for $\log(x)/(1-x) = \sum \log(x) x^n$ converges uniformly for $|x|<1-\epsilon$ and that the leftover part of the integral must be small since $\log(x)~(1-x)$ for $x$ near $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{1}{x-1} = -(1 + x + x^2 + \ldots)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{m}\ln\pars{x} \over x - 1}\,\dd x
     =\sum_{r = m + 1}^{\infty}{1 \over r^{2}}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{x^{m}\ln\pars{x} \over x - 1}\,\dd x}
> =\lim_{\mu \to m}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> =\lim_{\mu \to m}\partiald{\Psi\pars{\mu + 1}}{\mu}=\Psi\,'\pars{m + 1}
> \\[3mm]&=\partiald{}{z}\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over r} - {1 \over r + z}}
> _{z\ =\ m }
> =\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{r + m}^{2}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{r\ =\ m + 1}^{\infty}{1 \over r^{2}}}
> \end{align}

See [${\bf 6.3.22}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) and
[${\bf 6.3.16}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm).

Comment: This poses more problems than it brings solutions: why are the interchanges of limits and integrals, of integrals and derivatives, of derivatives and series, and so forth, valid? (Note also that the détour by the digamma function is quite unnecessary.)